# Does transformation of r into Fisher z benefit a meta-analysis?

Tags: correlation, variance, sampling, meta-analysis

Usually $r$ is transformed into Fisher $z$ to test difference between two $r$ values. But, when a meta-analysis is to be performed, why we should take such a step? Does it correct for measurement error or non-sampling error and why should we assume that $r$ is an imperfect estimate of population correlation?

Comment: The last part of your question ("Why should we assume that r is an imperfect estimate of population correlation?") is somewhat unrelated to the previous part. And what do you mean by "imperfect"? Do you mean biased?

Comment: @subhash: Can you state more precisely what you mean by "correct for measurement error or non-sampling error"?  Answering your question might be easier if you could define these terms unambiguously, such as be expressing them in terms of things such as random variables, distributions, parameters, or estimators.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is actually quite a bit of a debate in the literature whether one should conduct a meta-analysis with the raw correlation coefficients or with the r-to-z transformed values. However, leaving aside this discussion, there are really two reasons why the transformation is applied:

1. Many meta-analytic methods assume that the sampling distribution of the observed outcomes is (at least approximately) normal. When $\rho$ (the true correlation) in a particular study is far away from 0 and the sample size is small, then the sampling distribution of the (raw) correlation becomes very skewed and is not at all well approximated by a normal distribution. Fisher's r-to-z transformation happens to be a rather effective normalizing transformation (even though this is not the primary purpose of the transformation -- see below).
2. Many meta-analytic methods assume that the sampling variances of the observed outcomes are (at least approximately) known. For example, for the raw correlation coefficient, the sampling variance is approximately equal to:

$$\text{Var}[r] = \frac{(1-\rho^2)^2}{n-1}$$

In order to actually calculate $\text{Var}[r]$, we must do something about that unknown value of $\rho$ in that equation. For example, we could just plug the observed correlation (i.e., $r$) into the equation. This will give us an estimate of the sampling variance, but this happens to be a rather inaccurate estimate (especially in smaller samples). On the other hand, the sampling variance of an r-to-z transformed correlation is approximately equal to:

$$\text{Var}[z] = \frac{1}{n-3}$$

Note that this no longer depends on any unknown quantities. This is in fact the variance-stabilizing property of the r-to-z transformation (which is the actual purpose of the 
transformation).

Comment: +1, this is really informative & on-point. I wish I could upvote more than once.

Comment: @Wolfgang Quite interesting. May be better, if the meta-analytic context was taken. r is an unbiased estimate (Hedges and Olkin, 1985). Should we convert it into Fisher's z for a meta-analysis of sample correlations? please explain from this angle.

Comment: @subhashdavar Actually, the sample product-moment correlation coefficient $r$ is *not* an unbiased estimate of $\rho$ (see, for example, Hedges & Olkin, 1985, p. 225). Leaving this aside, the point of my answer was essentially: yes, you should transform.

Comment: @ Wolfgang Please read further if the sample-size is moderately large(say over 15, the bias of the sample correlation r is seldom of practical concern. Even the smaller samples .... the bias is ngligble. Moreover, the formulas cited in the earlier response appear to have a purpose that corrects for sampling error. I wish we could talk about measurement error.

Comment: Yes, I know that the bias is usually negligible (and in practice is never corrected for), but it is not correct to say that $r$ is unbiased. Also, the formulas do not *correct* for sampling error. They are simply used to calculate the sampling variance, which is then used to compute a weighted average of either the raw of transformed correlations. Measurement error is another issue. Using the [attenuation correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correction_for_attenuation), we can also correct a correlation for measurement error.

Comment: For more details on various methods for conducting meta-analyses with correlation coefficients, you may want to take a look at the book by Ralf Schulze [(amazon link)](http://www.amazon.com/Meta-Analysis-Comparision-Approaches-Ralf-Schulze/dp/0889372802/).

Comment: @Wolfgang, Thanks for the nice-attempt.However, let us note that r is unbiased (for measurement error). The KP formula (product moment correlation) takes care of the error by dividing the COV by SD of X and Y.

Comment: @subhash: Can you clarify what you mean by "r is unbiased (for measurement error)"?  Are you referring to a notion from classical test theory, perhaps as used by F. Schmidt, J. Hunter, and several of their colleagues and other authors in meta-analytic techniques for validity generalization?  As you may know, their methods emphasize estimating the between-studies mean and variance of "true" correlations that have been "corrected" for "artifacts" (e.g., unreliability, range restriction, dichotomization).

Comment: If we take a random-effects view of meta-analysis, where $\rho$ varies randomly (e.g., among studies), we might also consider whether $\rho$ or its Fisher-z counterpart $\zeta = \tanh^{-1} \rho$ better satisfies any meta-analytic assumptions about the effect-size parameter.  For example, it's often unclear whether $\rho$ or $\zeta$ is more likely to be normally distributed, which some procedures assume (e.g., certain maximum-likelihood estimators and "credibility" or prediction intervals).

Comment: The comment gives some very useful clarity of thoughts about the meta-analysis assumptions.

Comment: Could you provide a citation or two arguing the opposite point—that r should be used—since you remarked that there is some debate?

Comment: There is some coverage of the consequences of transforming (or not) in the Schulze book "Meta-analysis: A Comparison of Approaches" mentioned by @Wolfgang. I too would welcome further citations if anyone has any.